# DrawToBitmap on Panel is blank

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

So I've written a class that has a stores some test results info and then a control that displays that info to the user. I want to put a print function on this class to draw the control at a full page size and print it. However it always comes out blank. The code see the panel as a control because it could be some other type of value. I figure there must be something simple I'm missing.

```
void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Size oldSize = printData.Size;

        printData.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(printData.Size.Width, printData.Size.Height);

        InvertZOrderOfControls(printData.Controls);
        printData.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, printData.Size.Width, printData.Size.Height));
        InvertZOrderOfControls(printData.Controls);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, e.MarginBounds.Location);
        bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\jdudley\Documents\File.bmp");
        printData.Size = oldSize;
    }
```

Following this advice of [this thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/298209/printing-panel-in-c-desktop-application) inverted the Z-Order of the controls but it didn't change anything.
The save call was added for debugging. It looks like it's actually rendering the background color of the panel without any of the controls.

Edit: This is in the context of printing but I have not issue with printing what so ever. My error is in creating the bitmap. The save line I added proves this because it creates a blank bitmap file.

Comment: How are you calling this event.  have you debugged to ensure it is being executed at all?

Comment: Inverting the Z-order doesn't make any sense.  Possible mishaps are controls that are just on top of the panel but don't have the panel as their Parent, fumbling the painting of a custom control by not doing so in its Paint event or using a control that doesn't support DrawToBitmap, like RichTextBox or WebBrowser.

Comment: Yes I've debugged it. I've looked at the bitmap saved by it and it prints a blank page. The control displays properly when I add it to a form so I'm not sure how it could be related to controls not having there parent. There are no custom controls.

Comment: Yes, I replied to your answer. I can save and print the bitmap fine. The bitmap is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your entire event to this

```
    void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(printData.Width, printData.Height);
        printData.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), printData.Size));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, e.MarginBounds.Location);
    }
```

**Edit**

This is my whole Project.  I created a panel named printData and I added two buttons, I attached an event to button1.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
    }

    void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(printData.Width, printData.Height);
        printData.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), printData.Size));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, e.MarginBounds.Location);
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pd.Print();
    }
}
}
```

You have to try this and see if it works, or else I wont be able to sleep tonight!!

Comment: lol then I don't think you can help me. This is exactly what I wrote originally. (I added the resizing later). Thanks though. I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually and get the answer up here.

Comment: This makes no sense at all.  I have tested this and it works, there is nothing wrong with this code, the problem has to lie elsewhere then.  Why don't you try starting a new project, add a panel with some dummy controls and try printing that using this method.  hrmm..  What setting have you applied to your print document before you call the Print() method?

Comment: Okay so creating it in a new project gives no problems. Maybe it's context? *testing* Ah ha! It works from a button as opposed to right after it's loaded. Now to figure out why before I move it out of the context of my sandbox and try and run it in different locations.

Comment: Feel free to upvote me for helping....  Wait?  What? Right after it's loaded.  you are calling it before it is shown to the screen, which means it is loaded but it is not SHOWN.

Comment: Well actually it does work in the Form1_Load event, I didn't think it would, so which load are you talking about.  printData isn't a panel it's a userControl isn't it?

Comment: It's not a userControl. Basically I have a method that loads the printData, adds it to the form and prints it. The add to form is called first and it's visible behind the printing dialog. Is there anyway to print a control that hasn't been shown? I'd hoped to be able to print the data without showing it to the user in certain contexts.

Comment: I don't think so because it uses the Paint information.  Obviously you could draw your own bitmap using the information g.Drawstring...  or whatever you need.  The other option might be to Show the user, print it, then immediately remove it.  But keep in mind that printing the screen (panel) is not usually the best way to display something in printed format, that is why most websites have a printer friendly version.  I would recommend creating your own bitmap, draw/write the information to it then print that bitmap.  I can help you if you want.

Comment: To continue, what I often do is iterate through your controls and draw them to the bitmap using their own text, Font, and Location. then the layout will be the same, no ugly beige background though, is that a pro or a con... you decide.

Comment: Thanks but these items were created for the explicit purpose of printing to avoid having to draw the a graph and table manually. I used ZedGraph (I know it's technically a custom control but it's been tested and works so I knew it wasn't relevant to this thread) and DataGridView in my panel. When I got it working my plan was to change the background to white to get ride of the beige.